# Scrollable 100% height main panel with fixed header and optional breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a difficult CSS problem to solve. I have an app that always has a header at the top of the page - say 75px in height. On most pages, there will be breadcrumbs too - 45px in height. Of course, the home page has no need to show the breadcrumbs, so the header will occupy less total height than other pages.

What I'd like to do is have the main view under the breadcrumbs occupy the rest of the space on the screen - for all device heights. Moreover, I want this pane to be scrollable, while the header/breadcrumbs are always on top.

This seems to be very tricky to do.

Here is an example describing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: You cant do this with CSS, you'll need to do it with javascript.

Comment: ..or you could use calc() but I'm unsure about browser support

Comment: I am unfamiliar with using javascript to solve this. I'd appreciate some assistance in that regard too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's that calc() solution I mentioned in the comments. If you don't care about ie8 and lower it's perfect for your use case. If you care for older ie versions you can look into IE's expressions. Here's the demo:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    height: 60px;
    background: orange;
}

.breadcrumbs {
    height: 40px;
    background: yellowgreen;
}

.content {
    background: #BADA55;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px - 60px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header
</header>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    Breadcrumbs
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo ut et sequi harum repudiandae beatae iure quod similique ipsa natus. Ex quia ducimus in molestias maxime consequuntur quos explicabo at quam voluptate aliquid earum nesciunt voluptatum aperiam iure eum maiores obcaecati iste expedita beatae. Velit vitae animi voluptate harum similique dicta suscipit quo nemo molestias maiores quae omnis obcaecati expedita officia rem tempora qui nostrum impedit magnam molestiae repellendus assumenda fugit recusandae quos iusto inventore labore dignissimos. Maxime aspernatur nam assumenda est iure quas ad incidunt porro ea saepe! Ut laborum eligendi nostrum quidem ullam natus nam tempora sequi magnam.</p>
    
</div>
```

and when you don't have the breadcrumbs you just add a class to the body (or a container) and use different styles: http://jsfiddle.net/cy83uL28/1/

```
.container.without-breadcrumbs .content{
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Here's a link to a jsfiddle demo in case you want to play a little bit with it: http://jsfiddle.net/cy83uL28/

Comment: I had no idea calc() existed. What a lifesaver. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use position:fixed on the header and breadcrumbs, so that they float above the other content and always stay on the page. It would allow the functionality you want, without a lot of headache or special methods. Simply add position:fixed top:0 left:0 to your divs css.

Comment: This will cause the content of the header to collapse. Another problem would be that the header will be over the content so he'll need to add padding-top to the content equal to the height of the header+breadcrumbs. The last problem is that the scrollbar will go underneath the header, so imho this is not a good solution

Comment: If he adds a height to the header, it will not collapse. Millions of people use the nav bar in bootstrap which has the exact same functionality, i would argue this is a more elegant solution, and is definitely more widely used, with all browser support